# How to load external Json file using karma+Jasmine for angularJS testing?/

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

Can anyone provide me an example in PLUNKER that how to load JSON file for karma/jasmine test.I want to read the data from JSON file for the test cases i am writing.I have been searching but nowhere they mentioned clear example on how to do it? I appreciate it if anyone can provide with the example.

Answer (score 14):

You can load an external json data file using require

```
var data = require('./data.json');
console.log(data);
// Your test cases goes here and you can use data object
```

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted? seems like a valid alternative to me. Some reason why using `require` is not desired?

Comment: @MondKin, I use require in my test files all the time to pull in necessary libraries and resources. I don't know why this was downvoted. I just upvoted.

Comment: I'd like to add that you need to use a trick when using require if you are trying to require a file that does not have the .js extension. The example above won't necessarily work as '.js' will be appended to the end and not be able to find `data.json.js`. The workaround is to add a fake URL parameter like `require('./data.json?test=')`. This will turn into `data.json?test=.js` which will still locate the file.

Comment: @RobertHenderson require('./data.json') works fine for me without your trick, but I see you were writing a couple of years ago.

Answer (score 7):

Set the path to find your file, in this case my file (staticData.json) is located under /test folder.

```
jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'base/test/';
staticData= JSON.parse(jasmine.getFixtures().read("staticData.json"));
```

You have to add also the pattern in the karma.conf.js file, something like:

```
 { pattern: 'test/**/*.json', included: false, served: true}
```

Comment: It looks like this requires jasmine-jquery library.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to read the JSON file from a webserver or a local file system? No one can give an example of loading from a local file system from Plunker, since it runs in a web browser and is denied access to the file system.

Here is an example of how to load a JSON file from disk in any Node.js program, this should work for Karma/Jasmine:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var filename = './test.json';

fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
        return;
    }

    data = JSON.parse(data);

    console.dir(data);
});
```

Comment: I want to access it from local stystem any(*.json) file using karma/jasmine for angularJS testing

Comment: jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'base/test/';
        staticData= JSON.parse(jasmine.getFixtures().read("staticData.json"));