# how to do unit testing for angularJs service using karma?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, karma-runner

I have a service named "dataService" which is used to get json data from url.This dataService returns some jsonData.Now after running "grunt test" I am getting error like "urlRoot normalized to '/*karma*/' and client args should be array of strings".Can anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load external Json file using karma+Jasmine for angularJS testing?/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003472/how-to-load-external-json-file-using-karmajasmine-for-angularjs-testing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following process:

- Define the URL in your `package.json`
- Require grunt in `karma.conf.js`
- Reference the URL via `grunt.readJSON`
- Use `array.concat` to construct the files array