# Read JSON file to a Javascript Array without JQuery

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON file similar to the following:

```
[
  "thing1",
  "thing2",
  "thing3",
]
```

Let's call this file `some-things.json`.

I have a JavaScript file in the same directory as this JSON. I need the JSON data to be read in as an array, used elsewhere in the JavaScript.

What's the best way to do this? Do I have to read the JSON into a string and then parse to an array, or is there a nicer way? *For example,* `array = ReadJSONArray('some-things.json')`.

I have looked for duplicates, but I haven't found any questions where the JSON is in a *file*, not a string.

Also, as stated in the question title, I don't want to use JQuery for this. I have seen a few questions on SO where people have asked this question, but tagged as and/or mentioning JQuery.

Comment: that does not look like a json

Comment: read this article, it may help you load the json file in your script: https://codepen.io/KryptoniteDove/post/load-json-file-locally-using-pure-javascript

Comment: @FlyingGambit care to elaborate?

Comment: @James — Try to parse it. See the syntax error.

Comment: this may help https://codepen.io/KryptoniteDove/post/load-json-file-locally-using-pure-javascript

Comment: @James I thought JSON is a collection name/value pairs. I understand now that it can even be a collection values. http://www.json.org/

Comment: @Claies The accepted answer for that question is JQuery. Also, I'm not running this JavaScript in a browser

Comment: @FlyingGambit Yes, I've tested this JSON and it parses successfully

Comment: I assume by that comment "not running this JavaScript in a browser" that you are trying to do this in node?  you might get better responses if you make that distinction, since node has a very specific way of dealing with the file system.

Comment: @Claies Sorry I didn't realise it was relevant, my mistake. The JavaScript is being called from grunt

Comment: in grunt, you have `array = grunt.file.readJSON('some-things.json');`.  does this do what you are needing?

Comment: @Claies unfortunately not, I'm running karma, and need the array of files in karma config, which is a .js

Comment: what about this then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003472/how-to-load-external-json-file-using-karmajasmine-for-angularjs-testing

Comment: unfortunately, your question still feels unanswerable, since you didn't really ask what you want to do, with the tools you want to use;  JavaScript is unfortunately not specific enough, and describing the tools you *don't* want to use isn't enough to explain what you *do* want to use.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For reference, I solved this by using:

```
var array = require('./some-things.json');
```

Answer (score -3):

> Do I have to read the JSON into a string and then parse to an array…?

In general, yes.

[XHR](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-responsetype-attribute) allows you to specify a response type of `json`, which lets you read the file over XHR and parse it in one go, but support is not universal.